# Uploading a video with YouTube Data API

Tags: python, api, python-3.x, youtube-api, argparse

Are there any differences between Python 2 and Python 3 in this code?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    argparser.add_argument("--file", required=True, help="Video file to upload")
    argparser.add_argument("--title", help="Video title", default="Test Title")
    argparser.add_argument("--description", help="Video description",
                           default="Test Description")
    argparser.add_argument("--category", default="22",
                           help="Numeric video category. " +
                           "See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list")
    argparser.add_argument("--keywords", help="Video keywords, comma separated",
                           default="")
    argparser.add_argument("--privacyStatus", choices=VALID_PRIVACY_STATUSES,
                           default=VALID_PRIVACY_STATUSES[0], help="Video privacy status.")
    args = argparser.parse_args()
```

When running the program I get:

```
error: the following arguments are required: --file
```

Comment: No, same on py 2.x and py3k. But the error message is already clear enough: the `--file` argument is required, and you didn't specify it on the command line. However, IMHO this is pretty stupid CLI design. Why the heck do you use a long option for a *required* argument (moreover, there's only one required argument anyway)? Just use a positional argument.

Comment: I used the source code from Google https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video

Comment: Stupid CLI design nonetheless, official or not.

Comment: `--file` isn't that long of a name.  One way or other the script needs to know what video file it should upload.

Comment: @4ae1e1 - the use of a required flagged argument in this example keeps it consistent with other examples in this guide.  `--file` isn't always required.  Changing it to a 'positional' just because it is required in this case would be more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Py2 and Py3 behave the same in this script.  The error message might read a little different, depending on the release.

The error message echos, in effect, this setting:

```
"--file", required=True
error: the following arguments are required: --file
```

How are you calling this script?

Comment: I'm calling it YouTube.py

Comment: This is a commandline script.  It's not an interactive program with prompts or windows.  You have to specify the video file name in the commandline.  Otherwise it can't do anything useful for you.

Comment: These Python scripts are meant to be run from a terminal window (in windows that would be CMD or power shell).